# powerpivot average of an aggregate

Tags: powerpivot

I may be missing an obvious solution but I am looking for a way to take the average of a summed value. For example I have profit at an item# level where each item is on a bill as well and I want average of the bills profit.

```
Item# | Bill# | Profit
1       1      100
2       1      200
1       2      100
2       2      200
```

If I just take the avg of profit I get 150 but I want the avg of the bill total which would be 300. Is it possible to do this? I was thinking something like Calculate(Average(Profit),Bill# = Bill#) but that is always true?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not totally clear how you intend to use your measure but there are some powerful iterative functions in PowerPivot that do this kind of thing. This formula iterates over each bill# and averages the sum of the profit:

```
= AVERAGEX(VALUES(tbl[bill#]), SUM(tbl[profit]))
```

The first argument simply creates a 'column' of the unique bill#s and the second is the summing the profit per bill#.

*assuming your table is called `tbl`*

Comment: I ended up using:
**=SUM([Profit])/COUNTROWS(VALUES(Query[bill#]))**
 because for some reason when broken down by month your formula was summing all the averages rather then averaging them?


Thanks for pointing me in the correct direction!